# Eigenvectors of difference of inverse matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse

I have two matrices $A$ and $B$, symmetric and positive semi-definite (in fact, they are covariance matrices), and I am interested in computing the eigenvectors of the matrix $A^{-1}-B^{-1}$.

<strike>From numerical simulations, it appears that the eigenvectors of $A^{-1}-B^{-1}$ are often well approximated simply by the eigenvectors of $A-B$</strike>.

Moreover, if I regularize the matrices $A$ and $B$ before inverting them, by computing the matrix $(A+k\cdot I)^{-1} - (B+k\cdot I)^{-1} $ (where k is a positive constant, and $I$ is the identity matrix), the eigenvectors of $A-B$ provide an almost perfect approximation, especially if k is large.

<strike>Is there a way to prove that the eigenvectors of $A-B$ are a good approximation of the eigenvectors of $A^{-1}-B^{-1}$</strike>?

**Edit**: in light of your (very helpful) comments, I expanded my numerical tests to larger matrices, where I can see that it is not generally true that the eigenvectors of $A-B$ are close to those of $A^{-1}-B^{-1}$.

However, this still works if I consider the "regularized" versions of $A$ and $B$, i.e. the eigenvectors of $A-B$ correspond to the eigenvectors of $(A+k\cdot I)^{-1} - (B+k\cdot I)^{-1} $ (where k is a large positive constant, and $I$ is the identity matrix). Is there any way to prove this?

**Edit 2**: I think I might have found the proof for this. There is a well known result that $(I-A)^{-1}= I+A+A^2+A^3+...$ (this can be shown by multiplying both sides by $I-A$).
My expressions $A+k \cdot I$ can be rewritten as $\epsilon \cdot A +I$ (for small $\epsilon$), and so I can approximate $(\epsilon \cdot A +I)^{-1}$ with $I-A$ because I drop the following terms.

Finally I have:

$(A+k\cdot I)^{-1} - (B+k\cdot I)^{-1} = (\epsilon \cdot A+ I)^{-1} - (\epsilon \cdot B+ I)^{-1} = (I-A)-(I-B) = B-A$

Please let me know if you have any other insights about this, and thanks again for your help!

Comment: Do you have any bounds on the eigenvalues on the matrices $A$ and $B$?

Comment: This is true if $A$ and $B$ are positive definite (otherwise, they can be singular) and $(A-B)^{-1}=A^{-1}-B^{-1}$. That is, $(A^{-1}-B^{-1})=Q\Lambda^{-1}Q'$ where $(A-B)=Q\Lambda Q'$...

Comment: Did you try with several randomly generated instances of $A$ and $B$. Strictly speaking, $A-B$ and $A^{-1}-B^{-1}$ will share the same eigen vectors if and only if $A$ and $B$ are commuting (which is also equivalent to saying $A$ and $B$ share the same eigenvectors). What you are saying is a bit difficult to believe.

Comment: @KarthikUpadhya: I have no bounds on their eigenvalues. However, see the new format of the question: I am considering k to be significantly larger than the eigenvalues of A and B

Comment: @d.k.o.: thank you very much for your healthy skepticism! :)  I realize now that my first intuition was wrong. However, I pretty convinced that the second "regularized" version works, and I would love to know whether there is any formal way to prove that.

Comment: @dineshdileep: thank you very much for your healthy skepticism! :)  I realize now that my first intuition was wrong. However, I pretty convinced that the second "regularized" version works, and I would love to know whether there is any formal way to prove that.